# Why is this T-SQL DDL not adding a column to my table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

We have a type of DDL construct that sometimes (but not always) fails.  The construct is:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'b' 
               FROM   sys.COLUMNS A 
                      INNER JOIN sys.TABLES B 
                              ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID 
               WHERE  a.NAME = 'BadgeID' 
                      AND b.NAME = 'AllianceIncentBadges') 
  BEGIN 
      ALTER TABLE dbo.ALLIANCEINCENTBADGES 
        ADD BADGEID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0; 

      EXEC Sp_executesql 
N'MERGE INTO AllianceIncentBadges USING IncentiveBadges ON AllianceIncentBadges.BadgeName = IncentiveBadges.BadgeName WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET BadgeID = IncentiveBadges.BadgeID;'
    ; 
END; 

go
```

If I run the 'ALTER' Table first and then the 'EXEC', all is fine.  However, if I run it using the above construct, the BadgeID field is not added and the EXEC throws an error for the missing column.  I use the 'EXEC' so that the parser doesn't throw an error (the parser will throw an error if the column doesn't exist at *parse* time).

Any ideas why this problem crops up from time to time?

Comment: Is it anything as simple as GO after the ALTER TABLE clause?

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE dbo.AllianceIncentBadges ADD BadgeID int NOT NULL Default 0;
    MERGE INTO AllianceIncentBadges USING IncentiveBadges ON AllianceIncentBadges.BadgeName = IncentiveBadges.BadgeName WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET BadgeID = IncentiveBadges.BadgeID;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> '2705' THROW;
END CATCH
```